# Pull type information from parent class to subclass

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I have this base class

```
class BaseComponent<T> {
    constructor(protected selectors: T) {}
}
```

**LoginComponent.ts**

```
const ADMIN_SELECTORS = {
    inputUserName: "foo",
    buttonLogin: "bar",
    textError: "baz",
};


class LoginComponent<T> extends BaseComponent<typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS> {
    constructor(protected selectors: typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS) {
        super(selectors);
    }

    get loginButton() {
        return this.selectors.buttonLogin;
    }
}


// EXAMPLE CALL
const login = new LoginComponent(ADMIN_SELECTORS);
```

Thanks to `typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS` I'm telling the TypeScript what the structure of `this.selectors` actually gonna be. This gives me autocomplete and typechecking when I'm working with `this.selectors`

```
get userInput() {
        return this.selectors.inputUser; // Property 'inputUser' does not exist on type '{ inputUserName: string; buttonLogin: string; textError: string; }'
    }
```

Nice!

However what I need to do now is to create a sub class `CustomerLoginComponent`.
This subclass should have different value for `inputUserName` plus on new unique property called `textCustomerName` in it's selectors object.

**CustomerLoginComponent.ts**

```
const CUSTOMER_SELECTORS = {
    inputUserName: "abc",
    textCustomerName: "xyz",
};

class CustomerLoginComponent extends LoginComponent<typeof CUSTOMER_SELECTORS> {
    constructor(selectors) {
        super(selectors);
    }

    get customerName() {
        return this.selectors.textCustomerName;
    }
}

// EXAMPLE CALL
const customerLogin = new CustomerLoginComponent(CUSTOMER_SELECTORS);
```

The error I get here is `Property 'textCustomerName' does not exist on type '{ inputUserName: string; buttonLogin: string; textError: string; }'` in this part of code:

```
 get customerName() {
        return this.selectors.textCustomerName;
    }
```

What I decided to do is to tweak `LoginComponent`:

```
class LoginComponent<T> extends BaseComponent<typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS> {
    constructor(protected selectors: typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS & T) { // Note ' & T'!
        super(selectors);
    }

    get loginButton() {
        return this.selectors.buttonLogin;
    }
}
```

Now there are no errors when I try in `CustomerLoginComponent`.

But what I can't figure out now is how to annotate of `selectors` in `CustomerLoginComponent`.
Basically what TypeScript is suggesting is to do this:

```
class CustomerLoginComponent extends LoginComponent<typeof CUSTOMER_SELECTORS> {
    constructor(selectors: { inputUserName: string; buttonLogin: string; textError: string; } & { inputUserName: string; textCustomerName: string; }) {
        super(selectors);
    }
}
```

*Sure thing I can't hardcode the object structure since it's a kind of "flexible" object (that's why I'm using `typeof`). And in addition it's located in the other file.*

My question is can I make `CustomerLoginComponent` know about the fact that the type of `selectors` is two merged object:

The one from the parent class (type of which I should pass somehow, I guess?) + `typeof CUSTOMER_SELECTORS`.

I tried to understand the `infer` keyword but I'm not sure this something I'm looking for...
Also I'm not really sure about this part:

```
class LoginComponent<T> extends BaseComponent<typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS> {
    constructor(protected selectors: typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS & T) {
    }
}
```

I guess my base class has a mistake

```
class BaseComponent<T> {
    constructor(protected selectors: T) {}
}
```

Since I still have to explicitly annotate the type of selectors in `LoginComponent` as `: typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS` otherwise it won't work.

To wrap up, as you might guess the example above has some core issues in design so any help would be appreciated.

Otherwise I would like to know how to annotate the type of selectors argument in `CustomerLoginComponent`

Comment: I'm assuming you already know this, but in case you don't, when you just call `super(...args)`, you can leave out the constructor. If this isn't just an example, then I'd suggest removing those to avoid any issues with matching the type.

Comment: @101arrowz You would be surprised how little I know :) Don't you mind posting an answer showcasing this? I don't quite get the idea

Answer (score 2):

### Generics

You are almost there with `typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS & T`.  I think you are getting confused by the two different `T` generics in `BaseComponent` and `LoginComponent` which represent different things.  `T` in the `BaseComponent` represents all of the selectors.  `LoginComponent` know that its selectors are type `typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS` so the only reason that it needs to be generic at all is to handle additional properties which are added by subclasses.

`T` can represent the just those additional selectors:

```
class LoginComponent<T = {}> extends BaseComponent<typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS & T> {
```

Or `T` can represent all selectors:

```
class LoginComponent<T extends typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS = typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS> extends BaseComponent<T> {
```

In both cases I set a default value for `T` so that it's never `unknown`.

### Constructor Arguments

So now we get to the issue of what arguments need to be passed in to the constructor and what type they are.  In all three of your classes, the constructor takes the entire `selectors` object.

This means that you cannot call `new CustomerLoginComponent(CUSTOMER_SELECTORS)` because you are not providing the admin selectors which are required by `LoginComponent`.  You would have to call `new CustomerLoginComponent({...ADMIN_SELECTORS, ...CUSTOMER_SELECTORS})`;

If you don't want to do that, we need to make it so that the classes get their selectors from the constants rather than through the constructor.  It's generally not a great idea to have a `class` be so tightly coupled to its data, but you are already tightly coupling it by having the typings depend on the `typeof` your constants.

```
class BaseComponent<T> {
    constructor(protected selectors: T) {}
}

class LoginComponent<Extra = {}> extends BaseComponent<typeof ADMIN_SELECTORS & Extra> {
    constructor(extraSelectors: Extra = {} as any) { // the typing here is not ideal because I wanted to make the extras optional
        super({...extraSelectors, ...ADMIN_SELECTORS});
    }
}


class CustomerLoginComponent extends LoginComponent<typeof CUSTOMER_SELECTORS> {
    constructor() {
        super(CUSTOMER_SELECTORS);
    }
}

// EXAMPLE CALL
const login = new LoginComponent();
const customerLogin = new CustomerLoginComponent();
```